Core Lightning: "Ran out of routes to try after 15 attempts [...]" Why aren't my payments going through?
I run a core-lightning node with six active private channels with two nodes (ACINQ, allNice | torq.co) and over last couple of months most of the payments that I attempt fail with the output such as this:
{
   "code": 210,
   "message": "Ran out of routes to try after 15 attempts: see `paystatus`",
   "attempts": [
      {
         "status": "failed",
         "failreason": "failed: WIRE_TEMPORARY_CHANNEL_FAILURE (reply from remote)",
         "partid": 0,
         "amount_msat": 50000000
      },
      {
         "status": "failed",
         "failreason": "failed: WIRE_TEMPORARY_CHANNEL_FAILURE (reply from remote)",
         "partid": 1,
         "amount_msat": 50000000,
         "parent_partid": 0
      },
      {
         "status": "failed",
         "failreason": "failed: WIRE_TEMPORARY_CHANNEL_FAILURE (reply from remote)",
         "partid": 2,
         "amount_msat": 50000000,
         "parent_partid": 1
      },
      {
         "status": "failed",
         "failreason": "failed: WIRE_TEMPORARY_CHANNEL_FAILURE (reply from remote)",
         "partid": 3,
         "amount_msat": 50000000,
         "parent_partid": 2
      },
      {
         "status": "failed",
         "failreason": "failed: WIRE_TEMPORARY_CHANNEL_FAILURE (reply from remote)",
         "partid": 4,
         "amount_msat": 50000000,
         "parent_partid": 3
      },
      {
         "status": "failed",
         "failreason": "failed: WIRE_TEMPORARY_CHANNEL_FAILURE (reply from remote)",
         "partid": 5,
         "amount_msat": 50000000,
         "parent_partid": 4
      },
      {
         "status": "failed",
         "failreason": "failed: WIRE_TEMPORARY_CHANNEL_FAILURE (reply from remote)",
         "partid": 6,
         "amount_msat": 50000000,
         "parent_partid": 5
      },
      {
         "status": "failed",
         "failreason": "failed: WIRE_TEMPORARY_CHANNEL_FAILURE (reply from remote)",
         "partid": 7,
         "amount_msat": 50000000,
         "parent_partid": 6
      },
      {
         "status": "failed",
         "failreason": "failed: WIRE_TEMPORARY_CHANNEL_FAILURE (reply from remote)",
         "partid": 8,
         "amount_msat": 50000000,
         "parent_partid": 7
      },
      {
         "status": "failed",
         "failreason": "failed: WIRE_TEMPORARY_CHANNEL_FAILURE (reply from remote)",
         "partid": 9,
         "amount_msat": 50000000,
         "parent_partid": 8
      },
      {
         "status": "pending",
         "failreason": "failed: WIRE_TEMPORARY_CHANNEL_FAILURE (reply from remote)",
         "partid": 10,
         "amount_msat": 50000000,
         "parent_partid": 9
      },
      {
         "status": "failed",
         "failreason": "failed: WIRE_TEMPORARY_CHANNEL_FAILURE (reply from remote)",
         "partid": 11,
         "amount_msat": 24540318,
         "parent_partid": 10
      },
      {
         "status": "failed",
         "failreason": "failed: WIRE_TEMPORARY_CHANNEL_FAILURE (reply from remote)",
         "partid": 13,
         "amount_msat": 24540318,
         "parent_partid": 11
      },
      {
         "status": "failed",
         "failreason": "failed: WIRE_TEMPORARY_CHANNEL_FAILURE (reply from remote)",
         "partid": 12,
         "amount_msat": 25459682,
         "parent_partid": 10
      },
      {
         "status": "failed",
         "failreason": "failed: WIRE_TEMPORARY_CHANNEL_FAILURE (reply from remote)",
         "partid": 14,
         "amount_msat": 25459682,
         "parent_partid": 12
      }
   ]
}

lightning-cli decodepay lnbc500u1pnsyhulpp52adw3d2e8j7dz865n2j68h0gv25pzfpkrk3n7zmeu9x0e3f6a8qqdqqcqzzsxqrrssrzjq222c0sfnhhs8sf2xl3slefkfvfz8ltqq6vxj9pwl9jcpjzrnshq5rfzngqqzpqqqyqqqqqqqqqqraqq2qsp5q55vex6ghdwey3x0e6mf9xq4yh0g9302j0qppd84vlnfgcrgtj2q9qyyssqrglwd2sk5ergcqrgdf7c9jk9dhqchpr8mg26p5328qw8xd8jg32ythkax933n8ulf2lnwnd7707s3gyw3llcepfx5k5337lqx2y897gp4ttp6u returns
{
   "currency": "bc",
   "created_at": 1728208799,
   "expiry": 3600,
   "payee": "0271173e6139975a9eda1363b47b2a03290e4adc2f89c32fec4737bb4422180a74",
   "amount_msat": 50000000,
   "description": "",
   "min_final_cltv_expiry": 80,
   "payment_secret": "0528cc9b48bb5d9244cfceb692981525de82c5ea93c010b4f567e69460685c94",
   "features": "024200",
   "routes": [
      [
         {
            "pubkey": "0294ac3e099def03c12a37e30fe5364b1223fd60069869142ef96580c8439c2e0a",
            "short_channel_id": "******x****x*",
            "fee_base_msat": 0,
            "fee_proportional_millionths": 500,
            "cltv_expiry_delta": 80
         }
      ]
   ],
   "payment_hash": "575ae8b5593cbcd11f549aa5a3dde862a81124361da33f0b79e14cfcc53ae9c0",
   "signature": "304402201a3ee6aa16a6468c00686a7d82cac56dc18b8467da15a0d22a381c7334f24454022045dedd3163199f9f4abf374dbef3fd08a08e8fff8c8526a5a918fbe0328872f9"
}

lightning-cli getroute 0271173e6139975a9eda1363b47b2a03290e4adc2f89c32fec4737bb4422180a74 50000000 10
{
   "code": -32602,
   "message": "0271173e6139975a9eda1363b47b2a03290e4adc2f89c32fec4737bb4422180a74: unknown destination node_id (no public channels?)"
}

Increasing the fee to 2% has not solved the problem, lightning-cli -k pay maxfeepercent=2 bolt11=lnbc500u1pnsyhulpp52adw3d2e8j7dz865n2j68h0gv25pzfpkrk3n7zmeu9x0e3f6a8qqdqqcqzzsxqrrssrzjq222c0sfnhhs8sf2xl3slefkfvfz8ltqq6vxj9pwl9jcpjzrnshq5rfzngqqzpqqqyqqqqqqqqqqraqq2qsp5q55vex6ghdwey3x0e6mf9xq4yh0g9302j0qppd84vlnfgcrgtj2q9qyyssqrglwd2sk5ergcqrgdf7c9jk9dhqchpr8mg26p5328qw8xd8jg32ythkax933n8ulf2lnwnd7707s3gyw3llcepfx5k5337lqx2y897gp4ttp6u, does not work:
{
   "code": 210,
   "message": "Ran out of routes to try after 4 attempts: see `paystatus`",
   "attempts": [
      {
         "status": "failed",
         "failreason": "failed: WIRE_TEMPORARY_CHANNEL_FAILURE (reply from remote)",
         "partid": 0,
         "amount_msat": 50000000
      },
      {
         "status": "failed",
         "failreason": "failed: WIRE_TEMPORARY_CHANNEL_FAILURE (reply from remote)",
         "partid": 1,
         "amount_msat": 50000000,
         "parent_partid": 0
      },
      {
         "status": "failed",
         "failreason": "failed: WIRE_TEMPORARY_CHANNEL_FAILURE (reply from remote)",
         "partid": 2,
         "amount_msat": 50000000,
         "parent_partid": 1
      },
      {
         "status": "failed",
         "failreason": "failed: WIRE_TEMPORARY_CHANNEL_FAILURE (reply from remote)",
         "partid": 3,
         "amount_msat": 50000000,
         "parent_partid": 2
      }
   ]
}

The payments never fail when I am trading on robosats, they almost always fail with kucoin and bitrefill.
I have six active private channels and one inactive private channel (its state is "AWAITING_UNILATERAL"),
listpeers returns:
"peers": [
      {
         "id": "03864ef025fde8fb587d989186ce6a4a186895ee44a926bfc370e2c366597a3f8f",
         "connected": true,
         "num_channels": 6,
         "netaddr": [
            "3.33.236.230:9735"
         ],
         "features": "a0882a8a6981"
      },
      {
         "id": "0326e692c455dd554c709bbb470b0ca7e0bb04152f777d1445fd0bf3709a2833a3",
         "connected": true,
         "num_channels": 1,
         "netaddr": [
            "sioo43tvkudx56ksir3ndwynv2df3356dpjc6s4yy3abjtcmsys6wnad.onion:9735"
         ],
         "features": "80000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a0008a8a51a1"
      }
   ]
}


whereas listpeerchannels returns this.
I use LN over TOR, my config is:
proxy=127.0.0.1:9050
always-use-proxy=true

Am I being censored?
